# Strange glitchy screen in android app when changing text in textviews

Tags: android, textview, refresh, lines

I have a screen in my app where several TextViews get overwritten every time the user presses a button. On most devices this works just fine, the TextView gets new text and it renders great. However, I found a device that doesn't do this correctly. After pressing the button once or twice the screen becomes all glitchy and the text is missing in spots and not readable. The device is an HTC Sensation (z710e). What could cause that? Is there anyway to 'refresh' the view or re-render it to make the glitches disappear? The user noted that taking a screenshot of the glitch usually seemed to resolve the issue.